# Apps for Pepper robot

Tags: mobile-robot, pepper

I recently googled about Pepper robot and I wonder how one could write apps for it and get money for them. As far as I know they have app store, but does it sell apps or give them for free? (All info I googled myself is rather incomplete and old - probably outdated)

Also I believe that apps for such (or similar) robots is the potential multibillion-dollar market. What do you think about that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about selling software and not about robotics, and the second question is asking for a discussion.

Comment: Chuck, well, it's more about Pepper infrastructure, its quality and perspectives

Comment: You don't mention "infrastructure", "quality", or "perspective" anywhere in your question. You ask how could one "write apps for it and get money for them," and then, "I believe that apps... is the potential multibillion-dollar market. What do you think about that?" Neither question is about robotics, and your second question wants a discussion based on your speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is [robotappstore.com](http://www.robotappstore.com/). But i really doubt it is that large of a market.